# IF statement for deleting in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables in my database called **Phases** and **Releases**. The first one contains a Foreign Key to the `Releases` on `Id` named `ReleaseId`. If I want to delete a `Release`, firstly I want to check whether there is any `Phase` in it (as in, there is any column in `Phases` containing the `Id` of a `Release`). If there is, I delete the `Phase`, and then the `Release`. Otherwise, I just delete the `Release`.

Therefore, I put together the following query written in my SQL Server:

```
IF (SELECT * FROM Phases WHERE ReleaseId='2002') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Phases WHERE ReleaseId='2002'
DELETE FROM Releases WHERE Id='2002'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Releases WHERE Id='2002'
END
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I am pretty bad with SQL, hence I couldn't figure out a solution for this issue. What is going wrong?

Comment: Your `if` does not appear to have an effect (other than introducing a race condition). Just do the two `delete`s without any `if`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just create a foreign key constraint on `phases(releaseId)` that references `releases(Id)` with a `on delete cascade` clause? It implements the exact behavior that you are looking for:

```
alter table phases 
add constraint fk_phases_releases
foreign key (releaseId)
references releases(Id)
on delete cascade;
```

Whenever a parent record is deleted, the constraint will automatically delete children records.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just do this:

```
DELETE FROM Phases WHERE ReleaseId='2002'
DELETE FROM Releases WHERE Id='2002'
```

The 1st statement will succeed only if there are rows in `Phases` with `ReleaseId='2002'` otherwise nothing will be deleted.
The 2nd statement you want it anyway to be executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Phases WHERE ReleaseId='2002')
```